# Erwartungen should always be used with "an"?

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german, grammar-identification, swiss-standard-german

My sentence:

The expectation of the grades are high.

Die Erwartungen von der Noten sind hoch.

Translator:

Die Erwartungen an die Noten sind hoch.

When I searched on Google, most random links have the phrase Erwartungen jdn etw.
But, the same phrase does not show in any dictionary.

Am I misunderstanding the usage of an? I think an is used to talk about vertical position of the object otherwise, it is part of some fixed phrases e.g. denken an.

Comment: I downvoted this question. The English sentence doesn't make sense. I don't know what "Erwartungen jdn etw" is supposed to mean or where you found that. I think the problem is that you expect prepositions to only enter into fixed relationships with verbs, but not nouns.

Comment: @DavidVogt  The context wherein the students are supposed to get good grades and it is expected from them that they get the high grades and not the low ones.
The expectation of good grades is high. 
Die Erwartung an gute Noten/ Benotung ist hoch.

Comment: @David Vogt: The phrasing of the English version is a tad non-standard, but the meaning is clear. I would have said "The expectation is that the grades will be high," but this is wordier.

Comment: Google isn't really the right tool for this type of issue. I'd recommend DWDS. Look up the word and click on the DWDS-Wortprofil link toward the bottom of the page. There, under "hat Präpositionalgruppe", you can see that the prepositions usable with "Erwartungen" are *von*, *für*, *an* & occasionally *auf*. There is also the phrase *allen Erwartungen zum Trotz*. You can get an idea which preposition is used when from the examples you get by clicking on the phrase. I think both *von* and *an* would translate to "of", so it is a bit confusing for an English speaker.

Comment: @RDBury I am not a native speaker, but where has *expectation of the grades* ever been used? The highest ranked Google hit for this phrase is this very question.

Comment: @NoishaStudieren Any clarifications you have should be edited into the question. As it is, I find the beginning of the question not very helpful: A dodgy English sentence is machine translated into German. If you have the expectation that English *of* is always equal to German *von*, you should say so explicitly. I don't see how the English sentence enters into the problem at all.

Comment: @David Vogt: Well, I did say "non-standard". The way the sentence is phrased it sounds like the expectations were that there would very likely be grades, not that the grades would be high. This doesn't make much sense, but it's clear what people are expecting is that grades would be high, so some words were dropped for brevity and it's up to the listener to fill in the ellipsis. But this is usually difficult for non-native speakers, and often native speakers don't realize when it's a problem. Writing for non-native English speakers is a skill unto itself and difficult to master.

Comment: @David Vogt: PS. I agree that a machine translator is not the best tool to use here. For one thing, they are even more likely to misunderstand an odd turn of phrase than a non-native speaker. So extra care is needed to make sure what you type in is as clear as possible to avoid the "garbage in, garbage out" phenomenon. The OP did attempt to further research the phrase on Google, but again, not the right tool for the job at hand, hence one of my other comments.

Answer (score 3):

The complete phrase is

> Erwartungen *an* jemand/ etwas *stellen*

This is a figurative phrase with the literal meaning *to put expectations to or at someone/ something*. In other words, the preposition *an* actually belongs to the verb *stellen*. In the sentence

> Die Erwartungen *an* die Noten sind hoch.

the idea of *putting* is no longer visible. But it is still implicit, as you could always expand it, for example:

> Die Erwartungen, die *an* die Noten *gestellt* sind, sind zu hoch.

Answer (score 2):

Actually *Erwartungen* does not urgently require prepositions, and the most idiomatic use may be without preposition. (You expect something and either it happens or it does not.)

> Die Erwartungen haben sich nicht erfüllt.

Now there are some plausible contexts:

1. from whom you expect something as in

Especially if you express that expectation, you address them to somebody and *an* actually specifies the target of that address. (Such a stated expectation borders to a *Forderung* [demand], for which *an* is by far the most common preposition.)
Example:

> *zu hohe Erwartungen an die Genomforschung*

Better would be a phrase using the verb:

> **Von** der Genomforschung hätte man sich mehr erwartet.

2. in which respect you expect something

> Bis Ende des dritten Quartals 2000 habe Intershop alle Erwartungen **hinsichtlich** (in respect to) Umsatzsteigerung und Ergebnis erreicht.

> Die Erwartungen **bezüglich** der Anzahl errungener Medaillen haben sich nicht erfüllt.

3. the measurable degree of what you expect

This reflects your example, e. g. one expects a good grade but just receives a mediocre one. The best translation I can come up with is

> Die hoch gesteckten Erwartungen haben sich nicht erfüllt.

I don't see, how expectations can address a grade, which is just a passive result, and therefore  I see no justification for *an* here.

Comment: Exactly! *Erwartungen an die Noten* doesn't make much sense. +1